# Reset videoDisplay

Tags: apache-flex, videodisplay, flex-mx

Trying to completely reset my mx videoDisplay component, so that it will trigger the Ready event when I load new content.

As of now, it will only trigger the Ready event if I load a new movie. If I try to stop it, clear it, and load the same movie again it wont trigger the ready function.

Any ideas how I can make it trigger the ready event again if loading the same movie?

(I have a "home" button in my app, that will "reset" the application to the state it was when you started it.. So I'm trying to set all the settings to default here. But I cant clear the mx videoDisplay component so that the ready event will trigger after loading movie #1, hitting "home" to clear it all to default and then load the same movie #1 again.)

Comment: The documentation says this is dispatched once for each FLV that is loaded. I assume you've tried setting the `source` of the `VideoDisplay` to an empty String or something, then back to the real value? Is there some other event you can use, like maybe the "stateChange" event?

Comment: I've managed to get it sorted now, but I'm not 100% sure what actually worked. But it works ^^
I did try to clean and set the source to "" before too, but I still had problems with it.